# Error in Pig Rank operator

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to use the pig Rank operator in order to split my data to bins based on there rank.

However, I keep on getting this following error :

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error to read counters into Rank operation counterSize 0

I tried manipulating this by filtering null values with no success.  I also assured my job is not running on parallel as I read that Rank can not work in parallel.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you paste your pig script?

Comment: A = Load ....

B = Foreach A Generate * , (tag=='1234' ? 1 : 0 ) as tag ;

C = group B all ;

D = Foreach C generate flatten(B) , COUNT(B) as field_cnt, SUM(B.tag) as b_cnt ;

E = Foreach D  generate * , ((float)b_cnt/(float)field_cnt) as entry ;

F = rank E by $variable ;

G = Foreach F generate * , CEIL(rank_E * $number_of_bins / field_cnt) as var_bin ;